# SSAS MDX Replace (all ) on the date Hierarchy with (YTD)

Tags: ssas, mdx

Hi i have a date hierarchy and i want to replace the (All) with a calculated period like instead of displaying (all) i want it to display (YTD,2016,2015,2014,2013 and so on is it possible

this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrrH.png)is the query thats producing the (all)

```
select {} on columns,
[Dim Date].[PA Dates].ALLMEMBERS on rows 
from MyCube
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an equivalent script in `AdvWrks`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Day Name].[All].[AllWeek] AS 
    [Date].[Day Name].[All] 
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      Except
      (
        [Date].[Day Name].MEMBERS
       ,[Date].[Day Name].[All]
      )
     ,[Date].[Day Name].[All].[AllWeek]
    } 
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS
 ,[x] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]

So converting to your cube it'll be something like:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Dim Date].[PA Dates].[All].[YTD] AS 
    [Dim Date].[PA Dates].[All] 
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      Except
      (
        [Dim Date].[PA Dates].MEMBERS
       ,[Dim Date].[PA Dates].[All]
      )
     ,[Dim Date].[PA Dates].[All].[AllWeek]
    } 
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS
 ,[x] ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

Comment: hi @whytheq thank you for the quick response, that worked great

Comment: pleasure sir - mdx is fun